# Fractional Schrödinger equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier  transform.

It is known that $\mathcal{F}(e^{-4\pi^2 i t |x|^2})(\xi)= e^{i |\xi|^2/4t}{(4\pi i t)^{-n/2}} \ (x, \xi\in \mathbb R^n).$

> My question is: what is $\mathcal{F}(e^{-4\pi^2 i t |x|^\alpha})(\xi)$ for some $\alpha >0, \alpha \neq 2$?

Motivation: This kernel appears in the evolution of fractional  Schrödinger equation.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the Kohlrausch-Williams-Watts function. There is no exact closed-form expression.

The numerical evaluation for $n=1$ has been studied in [Fourier Transform of the Stretched Exponential Function: Analytic Error Bounds, Double Exponential Transform, and Open-Source Implementation libkww](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4796) (2009).

There exists an analytic approximation, described in [Relationship between the time-domain Kohlrausch-Williams-Watts and frequency-domain Havriliak-Negami relaxation functions](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.44.7306) (1991).